# Here variable 'pass' can't parse to $_post['action']=='edit'

Tags: php, mysql

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
        <input type="type" value="<?php echo $row['rcode'];?>" name="pass" id="pass"/>
        <input type="submit"  name="edit" class="btn btn-primary" value="edit"/>
        <input type="submit"  name="delete" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

then

```
if($_POST['action']=='edit'){

 echo  $rcode1=$_REQUEST['pass'];
    $sqlup="select * from transport_details where rcode='$rcode1'";
```

Comment: Your question and attempts are not clear at all

Comment: This has a SQL injection vulnerability in the code.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: update key is not get parsed???

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: @jibinkj Please rephrase your question, i cant even comprehend what exactly is the problem...

Comment: @indago  here $rcode1 is not getting????thats the problem

Comment: @BartoszT Thanksssssss it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no input named `action`. Your current code is unreachable.

The `$_POST` assoc gets its keys by attribute `name`. E.g.

```
<input type="text" name="authorName" />

<?php
    echo $_POST['authorName'];
?>
```

Your code should be like (in PHP file)

```
if (isset($_POST['edit'])) { ... }
```

**OR** (in HTML file)

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
        <input type="type" value="<?php echo $row['rcode'];?>" name="pass" id="pass"/>
        <input type="submit"  name="action" class="btn btn-primary" value="edit"/>
        <input type="submit"  name="action" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your php...

```
if (isset($_POST['edit'])) { 
    echo  $rcode1=$_POST['pass'];
    $sqlup="select * from transport_details where rcode='".$rcode1."'";
 }
```

assuming your html is like this...

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
        <input type="type" value="<?php echo $row['rcode'];?>" name="pass" id="pass"/>
        <input type="submit"  name="action" class="btn btn-primary" value="edit"/>
        <input type="submit"  name="action" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

you should be able to get the value